# Why does a shell variable containing a piped command fail while a non-piped command works as intended?

Tags: bash, shell

I've been writing a script to clear areas of disk storage devices, but have been running into many issues.

Consider the following cases:

1. Direct, Non-Piped - Directly executing the command

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512k seek=256 count=4096 conv=notrunc iflag=count_bytes,nocache,fullblock oflag=seek_bytes 2> /tmp/output & dd_pid=$!
   ```

   **Expected Behavior** Typing this directly in terminal / running directly through a script works perfectly fine.
2. Indirect (Variable), Non-Piped - Executing the command through a variable

   ```
   dd_command="dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512k seek=256 count=4096 conv=notrunc iflag=count_bytes,nocache,fullblock oflag=seek_bytes"
   $dd_command 2> /tmp/output & dd_pid=$!
   ```

   **Expected Behavior**. Also works perfectly fine, just as `1.`
3. Direct, Piped - Attempting to write all `1`s to the disk area

   ```
   tr '\000' '\377' < /dev/zero | dd of=/dev/sdX bs=512k count=4096 conv=notrunc iflag=count_bytes,nocache,fullblock 2> /tmp/output & dd_pid=$!
   ```

   **Secondary Issues** While this command performs its primary task of writing to the disk to completion, it hangs/terminates after a short period if the `seek` / `oflag=seek_bytes` parameters are present from `1.`.
4. Indirect (Variable), Piped -

   ```
   dd_command="tr '\000' '\377' < /dev/zero | dd of=/dev/sdX bs=512k count=4096 conv=notrunc iflag=count_bytes,nocache,fullblock"
   $dd_command 2> /tmp/output & dd_pid=$!
   ```

   **PRIMARY ISSUE** Regardless of flags, and I've tried removing all of them and even the `seek` and `count` parameters, this command will always fail after a few minutes/process terminated. It seems because I stored this command into a variable and then execute the command by calling the variable, as opposed to directly calling the command.

*Questions*

1. Why does calling this type of piped command via a variable instead of direct result in a crash?
2. Why do the additional flags in the piped command cases cause the command to fail?

*Other Notes*

Outputs to the file in all cases were performed by calling `kill -USR1 $dd_pid`. This worked as intended for the cases `1.` and `2.`, but for the cases that didn't, would be an additional cause (even earlier termination of the program) if this signal was sent to the process. It was **not** required to see the termination of the program though, but unclear why it would terminate the program at all.

Answer (score 3):

This is the wrong way to store a complex command.

Parsing is done *before* any parameter expansions. Although an unquoted parameter expansion undergoes word-splitting, the result is *not* reparsed. A `|` is just another argument to `tr`, not a shell metacharacter that defines a pipeline between `tr` and `dd`.

If you want to store complicated commands, use a function.

```
$ dd_command () {
>  tr '\000' '\377' < /dev/zero | 
>    dd of=/dev/sdX bs=512k count=4096 conv=notrunc iflag=count_bytes,nocache,fullblock
> }
>
$ dd_command 2> /tmp/output & dd_pid=$!
```

This also simplifies quoting, as the body of the function doesn't have to be quoted as the RHS of a parameter assignment needs to be.